# django-tagging or django-taggit, or something else?

Tags: django, tagging

Anyone have a recommendation for a tagging system in Django? django-tagging seems to be able to do everything short of cooking and vacuuming for you, but it hasn't been updated in more than a year. django-taggit looks simpler but equally as useful, and is quite active, at least recently.

However, neither of these apps seem to feature a tag cloud. I mean a real tag cloud, complete with the HTML and the styling and all that. Not a tag by model (which is a feature in django-tagging, pretty neat), or anything like that. Just a straight up tag cloud.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I prefer django-tagging, just because I'm more familiar with it's API. I had some quirky behavior with django-taggit, and switched back to django-tagging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Quirky behavior such as what? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Tags weren't getting saved when doing an update, which was kind of a biggie.

Comment: tagging stuff are really simple, you can make one tagging app in django by yourself, just read django ContentTypes documentation

Answer (score 10):

It's worth referring to djangopackages for these sorts of questions; http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/tagging/

You can see that you mentioned the two most popular with the others being hardly counted.

Personally I choose django-taggit. It's simpler, maintained by Django core devs and it has more recently been updated. It's also reassuring that the tox.ini in the django-taggit repository shows its tested against all the relevant python versions.

For me, django-tagging was bloated with more features than I would need but I understand they could be useful in some casses.

Answer (score 3):

if tag cloud is what you concern, you can try [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) combined with [django-taggit-templatetags](https://github.com/feuervogel/django-taggit-templatetags/). follow the instruction in the document in the second link, it's easy to implement your own tag cloud with few lines of template. hope this helps.